# Alternative to Using attributes to drive dialog creation

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I have a class that can generate a dialog box with controls that are defined through an Attribute on a class property. Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DialogControl("Total Amount")]
    public Int32 Total { get; set; }
}
```

Using reflection, I generate a dialog box with a NumericUpDown for the `Total` property. After the dialog is dismissed, the value from the dialog is set into the property. This works well.

But, the attribute clutters up my class a bit. I want to explore other designs or possibilities to get similar functionality without having to add attributes to properties in the class.

How would you design and implement such a system?

EDIT: Assume that classes similar to `MyClass` are already designed and will be client-facing. The code that does the class-to-dialog conversion is internal.

Comment: You could make the attribute a class attribute which gets properties names and suiting texts as "Total Amount", for example: `[ClassDialogControls("Total", "Total Amount", "OtherProp", "Other Text")]`. You might consider that "cleaner"... Anyway, I think your implementation is pretty awesome, although I don't see the actual need for it.

Comment: The implementation cuts down on setting up and displaying the dialog, which happens many times in my application. I was thinking of setting up another class to do the dialog setup, like a bridging class that adds in this metadata for dialog creation.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use a fluent interface. This is a piece of working code that I worte as a proof of concept for a project. I don't like attributes either so with this approach you shouldn't have to annotate your clases

```
var builder = new DialogBuilder<Foo>();

        var dlg = builder
            .CreateTab("Foo")
                .CreateGroup("Bar")
                    .CreateCtrl("ctrl_Id", "Id"/*[Label]*/, Align.Left)
                    .BindTo(x => x.Id)
            .Build();
```

This code creates a form with a tab and a group on it and then adds a control wich is binded to the property Id from the Foo class. (You can also specify validations, show on some condition, hide on some other and so on an so forth)
As you can see this approach is unintrusive and you don't have to touch your model clases in order to get your dialogs working.
If you want you can download the whole project from here

http://www.amiralles.com.ar/descargas/fluentdialog.zip

PS: There's no documentations, just unit tests.

Comment: Some say that unit tests are the best type of documentation. I tend to agree. Thanks for this!